# If I toggle Badass Bonus Stats, does it also save for teammates?

Tags: borderlands-2

When one toggles Bonus Stats (Enables/Disables BADASS RANK), it triggers a save for me. Does it also trigger a save for other players in my game?
[image: BADASS RANK character menu with BONUS STATS DISABLED]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, toggling Badass Bonus Status does not save for others. Tested it.